# Какие характеристики необходимы компьютеру чтобы установить Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Какие характеристики необходимы компьютеру чтобы установить Django?

Comment: Практически любые. Остальное зависит от того какую БД будете использовать, насколько прожорливые вычисления будете делать

Comment: Был в гостях у родителей, понадобилось внести правки в один из моих проектов на Django, запустил его на компьютере, купленном в 2004-м году.

Comment: Есть питон, есть немного оперативки — джанга неизбежно установится и запустится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одно ядро 1ГГц, 256МБ памяти, 120МБ на жестком диске будет достаточно для комфортной работы.

Answer (score 0):

Характеристики при установке практически не важны(главное на ставить на калькулятор). Характкристики Вашего ПК влияют на выбор среды разработки. Если у вас мощный ПК используйте pycharm, в противном случае sublime text 3